# How to get value after comma with a space following the comma

Tags: string, perl

In Perl, how do you take a string like...

```
Doe, John
```

and get the first name value after the comma since there's a space after the comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'Doe, John';

my ($lname, $fname) = map { s/^\s+//;  # strip leading spaces
                            $_         # return the modified string
                        } split ',', $string;

print "$fname\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
($lname,$fname) = split(/,\s+/,$string,2);
```

[split](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#split) the string where you find a comma followed by one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: This unnecessarily insists on at least one space after every comma, even though you have accounted for the case where there are two or more spaces, as well as limiting the result to no more than two fields.